# Editing JSON file with HTTP request to Flask server from other computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I couldn't think of a good title that really described what I'm looking for so I did my best. Basically I have a Flask server that has several endpoints. It holds data in a JSON file on my system. I have an endpoint called "/update_json" which I can pass a paramater like http://127.0.0.1:5000/update_json?json_key=json_value and it will update the json file with the key and value passed. So if I'm not mistaken it might not work on other system's since they won't have the json file correct? The specific code looks like this

```
@app.route("/update_json")
    def update_json():
    args = request.args
    args = jsonify(args)
    with open("static/data.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for key in args.json:
        data["test"][key] = args.json[key]
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    with open("static/data.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
    if request.args:
        return "Succesfully updated the JSON"
    else:
        return "Please include some keys and values to update the JSON
```

if this won't work on other systems what's a possible solution. Thanks in advance